# Text property of a TextBox is empty when an async PostBack occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback, master-pages

I've had a look at lots of posts and I feel like I'm going crazy as nothing I've tried seems to work. I simply want to click a button and retrieve the value of a textbox.

I'm using web forms with a site.master so not sure if this could be affecting the problem, but most of the solutions I've seen don't appear to be using a site.master.

I'm not binding the textbox, initially I just wanted to create a contact form.

```aspx
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="Blackburn_Pulse.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script>$("#menuAbout").addClass("navi-active");</script>

    <div class="contentBody">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tb_Test" EnableViewState="true" CausesValidation="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_Test" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Test_Click" Text="send test" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_Test" EventName="click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

```cs
public partial class About : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Page.Master.EnableViewState = true;

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            var test_var = tb_Test.Text; //returning empty
        }
    }

    protected void btn_Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var test_var = tb_Test.Text; //returning empty
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
site.master.cs

```
    public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindCategories();
        }
    }

    protected void BindCategories()
    {
        Categories Categories = new Categories();
        rpt_categories.DataSource = Categories.Get_Categories();
        rpt_categories.DataBind();
    }

    protected void lb_newsCat_Command1(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "naviTo":
                //Redirect user to selected category
                Response.Redirect("~/" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to reproduce the problem. Put a Label inside the UpdatePanel and add `Label1.Text = tb_Test.Text;` in `btn_Test_Click` to visualize the result. If the label remains empty you are probably resetting the value of `tb_Test` somewhere.

Comment: Just tried that, same thing happened the label is blank. The code above is for that page, there is no other code other than my site.master. The site.master only binds the websites navigation bar in a if(!Page.IsPostBack) so I'm struggling to see what could be resetting the value...

Comment: I think it is something to do with site.master. I've just added a blank web form that doesn't contain a site.master template and it works. I have updated my post with the site.master code. Nothing looks untoward to me...

Comment: A Master page should not influence the PostBack values on a page without some explicit coding. And the Master Page code you posted has nothing to do with the Page, or so it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm converting a PHP website to an ASP.net website. Turns out I had another HTML form tag on a search box that I haven't started working on yet.

Unfortunately the debugger doesn't throw an error if you have another form tag so anybody else who's just spent hours of their lives searching, double check you don't have more than 1 form tag!

In my site.master.aspx file, I had a search box as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="?">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Once I took the extra form tag out, everything worked fine.

Comment: Please add the corresponding code to better understand what the issue was. Otherwise this thread won't be very helpful. For example, were those `<form>` tags nested? Did you missed the `runat="server"` on any or both of those two `<form>`s? Etc. Please realize you didn't include any `<form>` tag in your original question.

Comment: The extra form tag was in my site.master.aspx file. I can't really include the entirety of my site.master but have updated my answer to demonstrate.